# Building iSpy plugin that uses opencv

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, visual-c++

I am attempting to make an iSpy plugin using opencv in order to process the image data.
iSpy is written in C#.NET and so must be their plugins, therefore I need a wrapper for OpenCV(which is written in C++). I tried using EMGUCV and OpenCVSharp; emgu based plugin didn't even run as a plugin(also it's very outdated) and ocvsharp has some big performance issues I can't bare for this project.

Since using C# wrappers wasn't an option anymore, I started making an unmanaged C++ project that implements the functionality I need for the plugin and built it as an x64 dll and tried to make a wrapper for this methods and functions to C# in order to use it on the plugin. So far, so good, the wrap works just fine when outside iSpy.
When I try to run the plugin that incorporates this projects via iSpy I get:

```
System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024885
Message=An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
Source=ImageProcessing
StackTrace:
   at ImageProcessing.WrappingMiddleman.Pootis()
   at ImageProcessing.ObjectsFinder..ctor(String path, FinderTypes finderType) in c:\Users\Matias Lopez\Documents\GitHub\CCAddons-Testing\FaceSurveillance\ImageProcessing\ObjectsFinder.cs:line 63
   at CCAddons.Main.InitConfig() in c:\Users\Matias Lopez\Documents\GitHub\CCAddons-Testing\FaceSurveillance\FaceSurveillance\Main.cs:line 162
   at CCAddons.Main.set_Configuration(String value) in c:\Users\Matias Lopez\Documents\GitHub\CCAddons-Testing\FaceSurveillance\FaceSurveillance\Main.cs:line 155
InnerException:
```

which, from what I've seen, means there is a problem with the solution platforms not matching or something.
Now, the problem is, I need the plugin to be built for AnyCPU, not x64, since iSpy won't even accept it as a valid plugin if not. What can I do to get my C++ dll to be run from the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I misunderstood completely what was going on. iSpy is built for x86 because it uses FFMPEG for x86(I honestly have no idea why they would do this), so I can simply build my plugin for x86 and be done with it.
Instead of using a managed C++ project I reverted to using PInvoke and making a wrapper class in the C# project. Problem solved.